# Asymmetry in p-p, n-n and n-p interactions

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, strong-force

Why does the asymmetry exist between the proton-proton, neutron-neutron and neutron-proton strong interactions in the nucleus (which results in nuclei preferring equal numbers of neutrons and protons)? Why is the neutron-proton interaction the strongest?

Comment: *which results in nuclei preferring equal numbers of neutrons and protons* No, this is not the reason why light nuclei have $N\approx Z$. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/323350/what-makes-the-number-of-neutrons-the-number-of-proton-similar .

Comment: *Why is the neutron-proton interaction the strongest?*  This is not really true in general, or even a well-defined statement. We do see states like the deuteron in which there is a strong attraction between the proton and neutron, but we can't make an apples-to-apples comparison with, e.g., a pair of neutrons in the same state, because that would be forbidden by the exclusion principle.

Comment: https://www.york.ac.uk/physics/research/nuclear/proton-neutron-symmetries/ "For example, it is well known that the nuclear force, at least when measured in free space, is not quite charge symmetric  - that is, the neutron-neutron interaction is just a bit stronger than the proton-proton interaction."

Comment: @BenCrowell https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Semiempirical_formula_for_nuclear_binding_energy "The symmetry correction term -d(N-Z)^{2}/A^{2} takes into account the fact that in the absence of other effects the most stable arrangement has equal numbers of protons and neutrons; this is because the n-p interaction in a nucleus is stronger than either the n-n or p-p interaction."