# Why will the number of neutron higher than the number of proton in the most of atom?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, neutrons, protons

The chinese website said :

> In the most of atom,the number of neutron higher than the number of proton

Does anyone know the reason?just explain it in easier way,

Or does anyone know if the number of neutron be less than the number of proton,what will happen with atom?why?

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/323350/what-makes-the-number-of-neutrons-the-number-of-proton-similar?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

The conventional explanation of more no of neutrons in nuclei is that because protons repel each other through the electrostatic force they must be diluted by neutrons.
The conventional theory of nuclear structure maintains that all nucleons are attracted to each other through the so-called strong force. And they will balance the electrostatic repulsion of proton - proton.
As you get to heavier elements, with each new proton you add, there is a larger repulsive force. The nuclear force is attractive and stronger than the electrostatic force, but it has a finite range. So you need to add extra neutrons, which do not repel each other, to add extra attractive force.

I have kept the answer at the basic level. And not went to more rigour and quantum world.

Answer (score 0):

One stable isotope that contains fewer neutrons than protons is helium-3( 2 protons, 1 neutron).  But in general, a larger number of neutrons acts to balance the strong nuclear attractive force with the repulsive electric force of the protons.  When nuclei get to a large enough size, they become unstable (radioactive) without extra neutrons, and for even larger nuclei i.e Uranium and above, they are unstable no matter how many neutrons they have.

Comment: Another stable nuclide with fewer neutrons than protons is $^1H$.